# Everything needed to solve this cipher is on Puzzling Stack Exchange

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, formation-of-numbers

> 5444   --->   lcxxfy
> 1906   --->   pstbqjilj
> 1582   --->   tcxvbpixrpejooat
> 1431   --->   dohhsfb
> 888   --->   uvqta
> 605   --->   noacomputers
> 618   --->   ylibz
> 425   --->   nspdd
> 381   --->   mbohvbhf
> 200   --->   bqnrrvnqcr
> 113   --->   ???

Everything needed to solve this cipher is on Puzzling Stack Exchange...

---

**What goes in place of the "???" and why?**

Comment: If what the answer's third spoiler block says is the case, then this puzzle will lose a lot of information once enough time passes to mess up those numbers, which is... not ideal. We want puzzles to be [solvable long after posting](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6834/69582), as our goal is to [create an archive of high-quality puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1699/69582)

Comment: @bobble:  another way to express it is the number of questions in each tag through the end of 2020.  That is a permanent piece of information.

Comment: @RossMillikan how about questions being deleted? Or undeleted?

Comment: @bobble:  Good point.  We just have to have the moderators block those actions on old questions.

Comment: @RossMillikan why would they block the deletion of old questions? Just so that this single puzzle will be valid later? What about legitimate moderation/curation actions?

Comment: Unfortunately I must agree with @bobble here. This puzzle will not remain valid in the future. Also, if my answer is completely correct, then the final answer is not found the same way as the other lines in the puzzle and as such makes it hard to confirm.

Comment: @bobble My bad, I didn't know that rule. I mean it is quite easy for someone to code a bot to count questions by date, but I guess if someone deleted a question it would be problematic. I tried to delete this but as there is an answer so I cannot.

Comment: @bobble lmao I voted to close my own question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In short, I *believe* the final answer is:

> [time](/questions/tagged/time); this is derived from the fact that there have been 98 total questions asked for this tag, and out of those 14 have been asked this year. If we add 14 to 98 we get 112 which is the number for the final line.

---

The cipher is:

> A Caesar cipher, and it's different for each line.

If you decrypt each line, you'll get:

> Popular tags from Puzzling SE where the dashes are replaced with the letter a. Take the first line for example:
>  
>  lcxxfy - `rot6` - [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle)

The numbers correspond to:

> The total number of questions asked for a given tag, minus the number of questions asked for the year respectively. Take the first line for example again:
>  
>  [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) has 5813 questions asked and 369 of them were asked this year. If we subtract 369 from 5813 we get 5444.

Utilizing the aforementioned techniques, we can arrive at the following conclusion for the known list:

> [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle); translated from `lcxxfy` with `ROT6`.
>  5813 - 369 = 5444
>  [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge); translated from `pstbqjilj` with `ROT21`.
>  2189 - 283 = 1906
>  [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle); translated from `tcxvbpixrpejooat` with `ROT11`.
>  1790 - 208 = 1582
>  [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern); translated from `dohhsfb` with `ROT12`.
>  1583 - 152 = 1431
>  [story](/questions/tagged/story); translated from `uvqta` with `ROT24`.
>  973 - 85 = 888
>  [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers); unencrypted.
>  689 - 84 = 605
>  [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus); translated from `ylibz` with `ROT19`.
>  652 - 34 = 618
>  [chess](/questions/tagged/chess); translated from `nspdd` with `ROT15`.
>  515 - 90 = 425
>  [language](/questions/tagged/language); translated from `mbohvbhf` with `ROT25`.
>  408 - 27 = 381
>  [crosswords](/questions/tagged/crosswords); translated from `bqnrrvnqcr` with `ROT1`.
>  227 - 27 = 200

Unfortunately, the aforementioned ruleset breaks down when attempting to find the final answer. The only options available near the last line in the sequence are:

> [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence); this is off by 1: 163 - 50 = 113
>  [three-dimensional](/questions/tagged/three-dimensional); this is also off by 1: 130 - 17 = 113
>  However, there is one **exact** match, but it uses addition instead of subtraction:
>  [time](/questions/tagged/time); 98 + 14 = 112

Comment: Typo it was supposed to be 113. you are correct. well done. you just have to figure out the rot on the name though.

Comment: @Ankit, can I get a hint on that relationship? If not that’s fine.

Comment: its similiar to how you got the other number...

Comment: @Ankit I’ve looked at asked this week/month, character counts, vote counts, watcher counts, edit counts, synonym counts, unanswered question counts, number of tags between tags, arbitrary relationships with data and descriptions, and more. Can I get a hint on how to find one side of the data set needed for calculating the rot value? For example, given a + b = c; where can I find a? Not what is a, just where to find it lol starting to go a bit bonkers here.

Comment: I will tell you that it involves something very close up in that list and something used already in your answer in a similar method as your answer.

Comment: @ Taco タコス Since the question is now closed, I will tell you that applying rot# where the # is the number of questions for the tag this year but not this month.

Comment: @Ankit I may be misunderstanding because I tried that. With the riddle tag it produces a value of 357 which is no where near 6 even if you divide by the 25 possible rotations. Can you give an example?